# How to use Malloc Detection in UE4

Tags: unreal-engine4

Unreal Engine provides a tool for malloc detection. However, I cannot use it because I get the following error:
`LogLeakDetector: Error: Cannot track leaks, MALLOC_LEAKDETECTION=0, PLATFORM_USES_FIXED_GMalloc_CLASS=0 (should be set as 1 & 0 in your Game<Config>Target.cs file)`

In my Game.Target.cs file I add GlobalHeaders.Add("MALLOC_LEAKDETECTION=1") and GlobalHeaders.Add("PLATFORM_USES_FIXED_GMalloc_CLASS=0") and rebuild the project but that doesn't affect anything. Does anyone have any experience with it?

Answer (score 1):

The only solution that worked was to build UE4 from Source. You can follow instructions [here](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/GettingStarted/DownloadingUnrealEngine/index.html). Simply add `#define MALLOC_LEAKDETECTION 1` in MallocLeakDetection.h before building the engine.